# Notion API doesn't return file URL anymore

Tags: notion-api

For several weeks, I fetch my articles in Notion with images and like the documentation, I had `name`, `url` and `expiry_time` in my File Object (as described one the doc )

[image]

But since yesterday, I get this:

```
        "Image": {
            "id": "bK%3A%3F",
            "type": "files",
            "files": [
                {
                    "name": "Super Astuto N&B.png"
                }
            ]
        },
```

Without the "url" property and I don't know why :/
I'm using the API version "2021-08-16"

Comment: Same problem here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working as expected again.
It was a temporary problem with them, I contacted the support team and they got back to me:

> This was due to a regression that was introduced the other day. Our team was able to investigate and resolve this issue.